# What is the purpose of this tilde in C#

Tags: c#, syntax, chipmunk

I'm trying to port this C# code:

```
public static ulong WILDCARD_COLLISION_TYPE
{
    get
    {
        int parse = ~0;
        return (ulong)parse;
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly, doesn't the `~` symbol perform a bitwise complement so what is the point of doing `~0`? and then returning it?

Comment: This will return a numeric value composed of 64 bits all set that could be used as a bit mask to test some kind of flag

Comment: It's equivalent of combersome `int parsed = unchecked((int) 0xFFFFFFFF);` you can put it just as `return 0xFFFFFFFFUL;` but it's easy to *miscount* the `F`s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [`~` Operator documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx):

> The `~` operator performs a `bitwise` complement operation on its operand, which has the effect of reversing each bit. Bitwise complement operators are predefined for `int, uint, long, and ulong.`

**For example:**

```
unsigned int i = ~0;

Result: Max number I can assign to i

and

signed int y = ~0;

Result: -1
```

so fore more info we can say that `~0` is just an int with all bits set to `1.` When interpreted as unsigned this will be equivalent to UINT_MAX. When interpreted as signed this will be `-1`